# How to select all elements of a table that match a set of ids in a crosslink table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, join

This will be a simple one for MySQL specialists.

I have one table with songs (songs):

```
id, song_name
```

And another one with tags (tags):

```
id, tag_name
```

And i have a crosslink table (tagXsong):

```
id, song_id, tag_id
```

I need a single query that returns all songs (from the *songs* table) which match ALL tags within a list of tags (provided as a joined list of IDs such as (57,58,60,63).

So in other words, i want to retrieve songs that have all of the tags in my list of tag ids.

What a shame asking for this!

Comment: Please note: the list of IDs is provided as a string. I ususally use a query such as SELECT * FROM tagXsong WHERE tag_id IN (57,58,60,63)

Comment: See this question and answer, many different ways to achive what you seek, with benchmarks: [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.id,s.song_name FROM song s, tagXsong x 
  WHERE s.id=x.song_id AND x.tag_id IN (57,58,60,63) 
  GROUP BY 1,2 HAVING COUNT(*)=4
```

This will give you all songs that have the four (57,58,60,63) tag_id's linked to them.

Comment: That's it! Wow, i'd never have arrived there myself :) Thanks! One question though - what's that GROUP business about, and why is the comparison to COUNT(*) made?

Comment: @user1018787 I use the grouping to bundle the songs as they would otherwise show up on a single line each. And having done that I choose only those lines that have a count of 4 (meaning all tags are present). I hope that explains it a bit better.

Comment: After reading your explanation and trying the query without the grouping i think i get it! Thank You!